# Match only two combinations and ignore the rest in REGEX - tableau

Tags: regex, tableau-api, regex-group

I have a dozen input ID's and I need to match only two particular patterns while ignoring the rest. I have a column that would flag those valid/invalid if the regex match is true.

Test string:

1.) B-123456

2.) 985463728

My regex should strictly match the above two patterns and ignore the rest. The first test string would have an alphabet B followed by a hyphen and then few digits while the second test string is purely numbers. Below is what I tried:

[Bb\d][-\d][0-9]{1,9}

Please help me out with this as I have tried weird combinations and I am missing out on something tiny. My regex includes other combinations as well which should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match either bB a `-` and 6 digits, or match 9 digits surrounded by word boundaries:

```
\b(?:[Bb]-[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{9})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X1xaNU/1)

If the number of digits can vary, you could make the bB and the hyphen optional and either match 1+ digits using `[0-9]+` or use a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) `[0-9]{1,9}`

```
\b(?:[bB]-)?[0-9]+\b
```

Or use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string

```
^(?:[bB]-)?[0-9]+$
```

Comment: This works partially as other combinations like these get through it. 

B12345,

B--12344,

B*12334.

I was looking for an expression that could only match the two patterns on my question.

Comment: @jinglyhk Then you could use anchors `^` and `$`  for example `^(?:[bB]-)?[0-9]+$` See https://regex101.com/r/w560yA/1